# Apps Script or Contextual Gadget to add UI to Gmail

Tags: gmail-contextual-gadgets

I have problem! I try to create a script that will add UI elements to Gmail. I have 2 scenarios:

1.) add ui button with image to bottom of new message dialog:
[new message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gmL1T.png)

2.) add ui button with image to bottom of contact popover: 
[g+ contact](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DLz5G.png)

And my questions:

1. It is possible add UI elements with any actions (e.g. alert())?
2. Google apps script or Gmail Contextual Gadgets should I use?
3. Can you write me example of code witch add example of UI to Gmail?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Its not correct that "nobody except the developers of those services have permission to access the interface" since you can write [gmail contextual gadgets](https://developers.google.com/gmail/contextual_gadgets), however those only show in the body of a received email and not on the new message window.

Can't be done with apps script either which does allow you to create web interfaces (not just for processing data) but you cant add them to the gmail window.

Best option is to write a browser extension and cover the case of gmail/inbox browser pages.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no.

Google Apps Script is really only a tool for processing data. You cannot add custom UI/buttons to GMail, because nobody except the developers of those services have permission to access the interface.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8689905/gmail-extension-gadget-api-how-to-add-a-button-to-the-compose-toolbar?rq=1) is another question that is similar to yours - it contains a good answer as well.

If you want to add your own buttons, you would need to write a browser extension.