# Using Google API from Gmail Contextual Gadget?

Tags: google-api, gmail-api, google-gadget, gmail-contextual-gadgets

Do you know whether is possible to use/call google API from a gmail contextual gadget? 
What I want to do is to add a button at the bottom of the email which will be used to backup the email (on my own server) with all the attachments.

Answer (score 0):

You can check this documentation about [Gadgets](https://developers.google.com/gadgets/?csw=1). Based from this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8689905/gmail-extension-gadget-api-how-to-add-a-button-to-the-compose-toolbar), you will have to create and inject the button programmatically. However, this will involve quite a bit of scouring the Gmail source code. Here are the [Gadget features supported in Gmail](https://developers.google.com/gmail/contextual_gadgets?csw=1#gadget_features_supported_in_gmail).

Another workaround to backup the email with attachments is to create [Chrome Extension](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions). Here is an [example](https://github.com/KartikTalwar/gmail-chrome-extension-boilerplate).